# get all rows preceded and followed by whitespace

Tags: postgresql

for example i have the following table (let's call it, `comodity`)

```
+-----------+
|name       |
+-----------+
|kemasan    |
|fe emas ex |
+-----------+
```

using the following query

```
SELECT * FROM comodity WHERE name ILIKE '%emas%'
```

give me two rows `kemasan` and `fe emas ex`, however I want to select only the second row `fe emas ex`. how to do that?

**PS: it's also SHOULD NOT preceded/followed by any visible character**.

Thanks in advance

Comment: presumably, ILIKE '% emas %'

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES
  ('blah emas blah'),
  ('vlademask'),
  ('emas1'),
  ('1emas'),
  ('emas'),
  ('1 emas'),
  ('emas 1')
) as commodity(word)
WHERE word ~* '\yemas\y'
```

Use a regular expression that matches words or start and stop markers.

Comment: A bit simpler if you just match word boundaries, i.e. `'\yemas\y'`. Also, given that the question is using `ILIKE`, you probably want the case-insensitive regex operator `~*`.

Comment: Or the POSIX method `~ '[[:<:]]emas[[:>:]]'`

Comment: Thanks @NickBarnes, I like your simplifications.   I didn't know those posix markers.  Something new every day.